# Extract data from mysql using Scala and spark

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark

I tried to run a Scala program to extract the data from mysql retail_db database. It throws SQLException.

**This is my code:**

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection

case class Categories(id: Int, department: String, name: String){
  override def toString: String = {"id: " + id + "department: " + department + "name: " + name}
}
object Orders {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    val url = "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db"
    val username = "root"
    val password = "cloudera"
    Class.forName(driver)
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
    val statement = connection.createStatement()
    val resultSet = statement.executeQuery(s"SELECT * FROM categories")

    while (resultSet.next()){
      val e = Categories(resultSet.getInt("id"),
        resultSet.getString("department"),
        resultSet.getString("name"))
         println(e)
    }
  }
}
```

**Spark submit command:**

```
spark-submit --class "Orders" \
--master local < path >/scala_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not
>   found."**

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with code. I think `id` column is not part of categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple you don't have a column named id in categories table (or it is not a Int). I suggest to run

```
val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SHOW COLUMNS FROM categories")
```

first which will return a [description](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html) of your table and then

```
   while (resultSet.next()){
           println(resultSet.getString("Field"))
           println(resultSet.getString("Type"))
    }
```

With this way you would see the actual field name and type.
Of course this assumes you don't have access to the host of MySQL or else 
you should simply connect there manually and see the table structure.

**EDIT:** The JDBC URL looked familiar, it is from cloudera's quickstart VM. Anyway the table's schema is [here](https://www.cloudera.com/developers/get-started-with-hadoop-tutorial/exercise-1.html) so as you can see it is not id but category_id.